# Different Frontend-Layouts in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

I'm trying to use different Frontend-Layouts in TYPO3. So I'm using this fancy TypoScript:

```
page {
    bodyTag = <body>

    10= CASE
    10.key.field=layout
    # Standardtemplate
    10.0 = TEMPLATE
    10.0.template = FILE
    10.0.template.file = fileadmin/template/content_template.html
    10.0.workOnSubpart = DOCUMENT_BODY

    # Variante 1:
    10.1 = TEMPLATE
    10.1.template = FILE
    10.1.template.file = fileadmin/template/index_template.html
    10.1.workOnSubpart = DOCUMENT_BODY

    includeJSFooter {

    jquery = fileadmin/template/js/jquery.js
    bootstrap = fileadmin/template/js/bootstrap.min.js
    app = fileadmin/template/js/app.js

  }

  includeCSS {

    robotoFont = https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,400
    robotoFont.external = 1
    robotoFont.media = all

    bootstrapCore = fileadmin/template/css/bootstrap.min.css
    bootstrapCore.media = all


  }
}
```

This is not working yet. Every single page is completely. Only a white page appears. I'm using TYPO3 7.6.16. Is there any issue in my code above?

Answer (score 0):

It think you are looking for this just place it in the PAGE-Element and rename the Path and also create some BackendLayouts named as value in layout 1. 2. 3. e.g. hope this will help:

```
10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
            file = fileadmin/templates/Page/Standard.html

            partialRootPath =  fileadmin/templates/Partials/

            variables {

                    layout = CASE
                    layout {
                            key.field = backend_layout
                            key.ifEmpty.data = levelfield:-2, backend_layout_next_level, slide

                            1 = TEXT
                            1.value = startpage

                            2 = TEXT
                            2.value = subpage

                            3 = TEXT
                            3.value = subpagespecial

                            default = TEXT
                            default.value = subpage
                    }

                    content = CONTENT
                    content {
                            table = tt_content
                            select.orderBy = sorting
                            select.where = colPos=0
                            select.languageField = sys_language_uid
                            select.includeRecordsWithoutDefaultTranslation = 1
                    }

                    header = CONTENT
                    header {
                            table = tt_content
                            select.orderBy = sorting
                            select.where = colPos=1
                            select.languageField = sys_language_uid
                            select.includeRecordsWithoutDefaultTranslation = 1
                    }
                    content2 = CONTENT
                    content2 {
                            table = tt_content
                            select.orderBy = sorting
                            select.where = colPos=3
                            select.languageField = sys_language_uid
                            select.includeRecordsWithoutDefaultTranslation = 1
                    }
                    contentfull = CONTENT
                    contentfull {
                            table = tt_content
                            select.orderBy = sorting
                            select.where = colPos=2
                            select.languageField = sys_language_uid
                            select.includeRecordsWithoutDefaultTranslation = 1
                    }
            }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not using the Fluid-Templates :/

Comment: I would recommend it. It's easy to use and future oriented and easy for maintenance check the wiki https://wiki.typo3.org/T3Doc/Fluidtemplate_by_example

Answer (score 0):

Please add a default variant in the CASE object. It may be that pages which are created anew do not have a '0' in its 'layout' column.

Did you verify that the subpart markers are spelled correctly?

```
<!-- ###DOCUMENT_BODY### begin --> 
Your HTML template
<!-- ###DOCUMENT_BODY### end -->
```

You could simplify your TypoScript template:

```
page {
    10 = TEMPLATE
    10.template = FILE
    10.template.file = CASE
    10.template.file {
        key.field = layout
        default = TEXT
        default.value = fileadmin/template/content_template.html
        1 = TEXT
        value = fileadmin/template/index_template.html
    }
    10.workOnSubpart = DOCUMENT_BODY
}
```